# npm vulnerability fixes require Angular 7, but will cause more issues in Ionic 3 project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ionic3

So I have an question regarding my Ionic 3 project. Using `npm audit`there are 10 vulnerabilities requiring fixes, but both fixes require Angular 7 and I know [Ionic 3 is only compatible with Angular 5](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/latest-official-version-of-angular-that-latest-ionic-3-supports/132986).

My question is, is there a way to resolve these vulnerabilities without upgrading Angular. So instead downgrade a plugin or possibly finding the root cause of the issue? Or can I ignore the vulnerabilities?

Here are the npm messages:

> Run  npm install @angular/compiler-cli@7.2.14  to resolve 2 vulnerabilities SEMVER WARNING: Recommended action is a potentially breaking change
>
> Run  npm install @angular/cli@7.3.8  to resolve 7 vulnerabilities SEMVER WARNING: Recommended action is a potentially breaking change

Answer (score 0):

try this, delete all files in `node_modeules` and run `npm install` then note the package that requires angular 7. then take action on t directly.

Comment: How would I *note the packages that require angular 7? And if I delete all node modules, Would npm install all of the needed modules again?

Comment: you would see the message in the console... about the  vulnerabilities in each of the packages as they install. `npm install` is going to install all of the packages listed in your ` package.json` file. you don't need to worry.